# Open Template.xlsx file and write data then SaveAs UpdatedTemplate.xlsx using perl

Tags: perl

```
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
my $Excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
    || Win32::OLE->new( 'Excel.Application', 'Quit' );
my $book = $Excel->Workbooks->Open('Template.xlsx');

# write to a particular cell
$sheet = $book->Worksheets(1);
$sheet->Cells( 1, 1 )->{Value} = "MyData";

# save and exit
$book->SaveAs('UpdatedTemplate.xlsx');
undef $book;
undef $Excel;
```

Please find my requirements below

1. Open `Template.xlsx` file
2. Write the values to the opened *.xlsx file
3. Then save it as `UpdatedTemplate.xlsx` file

Issues:

1. `UpdatedTemplate.xlsx` is not being generated.
2. I am unable to find the `UpdatedTemplate.xls`x file. Sometimes it shows the message "UpdatedTemplate.xlsx is already existing in this location. Do you want to replace it?", but the file is not generated if i say yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not give complete path in SaveAs('UpdateTemplate.xlsx') then it will save in Documents folder of windows by default. You can check there itself. So better give the absolute path in the methods open and saveas

```
   use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
   use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel'; 
   my $Excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
     || Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit');
    my $book  = $Excel->Workbooks->Open('D:\Perl\Template.xlsx');


    # write to a particular cell
    $sheet = $book->Worksheets(1);
    $sheet->Cells(1,1)->{Value} = "MyData";

    # save and exit
    $book->SaveAs('D:\Perl\UpdatedTemplate.xlsx');
    $book-> close;
```

Comment: Will it also do this with Save()?  I'm trying to figure out why my inherited script is saving two copies of an Excel spreadsheet - one copy where it is supposed to (fully defined pathname), and another copy to the default user profile's Documents folder (the script is running as SYSTEM).  I probably ought to start a new question for this, as it's really tangential to the original question.